# Tika app failed with causeForTermination='MAIN_LOOP_EXCEPTION_NO_RESTART'

Tags: java, linux, automation, apache-tika, tika-server

I am using tika-app-1.14.jar to convert my pdf and image files to text using command-line.

```
java -jar tika-app-1.14.jar -t -i /inputFolder -o /OutputFolder
```

It runs well but when I run the same script from the automation tool it fails, saying `*causeForTermination='MAIN_LOOP_EXCEPTION_NO_RESTART'*` and does not convert the files to text. Couldn't find the cause of this issue.

Comment: What tool are you using? Only that doesn't look like a Tika exception

Comment: I'm using CA workload automation. I have seen this exception in the java code of tika-app. https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-batch/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/batch/BatchProcess.java It says it is because of a timeout, but do you have any idea how we can handle it from command line.